# Objective C weird IF syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax

As having most of my experience in PHP, I have seen lots of new syntax rules. Most of them I have accepted and understood, but there is one that just makes no sense to me.

```
currentNumber = 0;
self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f", result];
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0; {
    currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
}
```

As you can see, there is a bracket after `result = 0;`. At first I thought it was just a shortcut, just like `[[something alloc]init]`, but when I rewrote the code like this:

```
currentNumber = 0;
self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f", result];
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0; 
else{
    currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
}
```

my app was not behaving as intended, even though the above has no syntax errors.

So my question is, what does this syntax mean? How does it translate to PHP if it even does?

Comment: it's ain't any wierdness, it's derived from c :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a single `if` statement, it is an `if` followed by a sequence of statements enclosed in curly braces. A better way of formatting this would be as follows:

```
if ([sender tag] == 0)
    result = 0;

// ---- if statement ends here ----

{
    currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
}
```

`result = 0` is the only part that is done conditionally; the rest, i.e.

```
currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
```

is done unconditionally. In fact, the block that follows the conditional could be rewritten without curly braces; this would not change its behavior:

```
if ([sender tag] == 0)
    result = 0;
currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
```

> why enclose `currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];` within curly braces?

There is no point in doing that. The intention may have been to enclose both `result = 0` and `currentOperation = ...` in the same block, but whoever wrote this code has made a typo.

Comment: It was no typo, I just rewrote the code to check it and the app was not behaving the same way. Im following some guy's beginner iOS tutorial, and he does have a weird way of coding, but this is not a typo. I can send you the project, it's a simple calculator.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0; {
    currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ([sender tag] == 0) { result = 0; } {
    currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if ([sender tag] == 0) { 
    result = 0; 
}
currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];
```

In other words, in your code only `result = 0;` is conditional - the rest is executed always.

Comment: I see, so why enclose `currentOperation = (int)[sender tag];` within curly braces? It's just more work and it does not look more clear anyways.

Comment: You're right - it's not necessary. This seems like a copy&paste error, not something done intentionally.